# How to get AMI usage statistics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I want to get the usage statistics of my public AMI such as the number of instances that have been launched from it. Is it possible to do so?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this information is not available.

You could possibly look through AWS CloudTrail logs and look for AMIs used when launching instances. This would only apply to instances launched **in your own AWS account**.

Comment: Thanks, John. At least, Is there a way to know how many times my public AMI is accessed by others using CloudTrail logs?

Comment: No, that would not appear because CloudTrail records **API requests sent to your account**. Accessing an AMI is not itself an API request. Any API calls to launch an instance using that AMI would appear in the CloudTrail of the account where the instance is launching. However, I think that AMIs provided by the AWS Marketplace would be tracked and counted, if you want to offer the AMI to a wider audience.